# How to add a measure in DAX?

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I am building a power bi report and need some help figuring a DAX measure out.

I have a table that contains Usernames. I have another table which contains Usernames, Error Count and Status, as "Accepted" or "Not accepted".

I want to get the sum of Error Count per username only if they are accepted.

Tables:

```
Table

Username
Avinash 

Table1

Username       Errorcount       Status
Avinash            2            Accepted
Avinash            1            Not Accepted
```

These are the measures I've created:

```
EXT :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'ERRORS AFTER DTX'[Error Count] ),
    FILTER ( 'ERRORS AFTER DTX', 'ERRORS AFTER DTX'[India Status] = "Accepted" )
)

EXT :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'ERRORS AFTER DTX'[Error Count] ),
    FILTER ( 'ERRORS AFTER DTX', 'ERRORS AFTER DTX'[India Status] = "Accepted" )
    , EXACT(Table1[Users])
)
```

Expected Output:

```
Username              Error Count
Avinash                    2
```

Comment: Can you please show us what the output was for your measures?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
ErrorCount :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'ERRORS AFTER DTX'[Error Count] ),
    'ERRORS AFTER DTX'[India Status] = "Accepted"
)
```

Comment: Yes,This is calculating entire sum of that column but i want it to match username list in dashboard which i created by using another table.

Comment: try this; create a table, use [Username] in the 'rows' parameter and [ErrorCount]  as the 'value'.

Answer (score 0):

This would give your expected output:

ErrorCount =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'ERRORS AFTER DTX'[Error Count] ),
    'ERRORS AFTER DTX'[India Status] = "Accepted", GROUPBY(Table, USERNAME))